# Merge data frames without Merge Function

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames called height.txt

```
ID:     1 2 3 4 5
Height: 67 60 62 55 69
```

and next data frame is weight.txt

```
ID: 1 2 4 5 6
Weight: 110 123 150 170 185
```

The goal is to merge these two data frames together, without using the `merge()` function in R, and the output should be in the image. How would I do this? This is for practice, I know `merge()` does the trick, but I am supposed to do this without it, it is for a class.

[image: Output]

## Edit:

Data in a copy&paste format.

```
ID <- scan(text = "1 2 3 4 5")
Height <- scan(text = "67 60 62 55 69")
df1 <- data.frame(ID, Height)

ID <- scan(text = "1 2 4 5 6")
Weight <- scan(text = "110 123 150 170 185")
df2 <- data.frame(ID, Weight)
```

Comment: How about `inner_join` from dplyr or data.table syntax? Are they allowed?

Comment: No, supposed to be manually or through vectorization.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Show what you have tried and if you get stuck, someone here may help you.

Comment: I do not know where to start, and how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple repeated use of `match`.

1. Create a data.frame with all the elements of the common column, `ID`, with no repetitions.
2. `match` the `ID`'s of each of the dataframes with the `ID` of the result `res`.
3. Assign the other columns.

Remember to create each of the other columns before assigning values to them.

```
res <- data.frame(ID = unique(c(df1$ID, df2$ID)))

i <- match(df1$ID, res$ID)
j <- na.omit(match(res$ID, df1$ID))
res$Height <- NA
res$Height[i] <- df1$Height[j]

i <- match(df2$ID, res$ID)
j <- na.omit(match(res$ID, df2$ID))
res$Weight <- NA
res$Weight[i] <- df2$Weight[j]


res
#  ID Height Weight
#1  1     67    110
#2  2     60    123
#3  3     62     NA
#4  4     55    150
#5  5     69    170
#6  6     NA    185

identical(res, merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE))
#[1] TRUE
```

## Edit.

Answering to a question in a comment about how general this solution is. From `help("merge")`:

> Details
>
> merge is a generic function whose principal method is for data frames:
>   the default method coerces its arguments to data frames and calls the
>   "data.frame" method.

The method `merge.data.frame` in R 3.6.2 is 158 code lines long, this solution is not general at all.

## Edit 2.

A function generalizing the code above could the following.

```
merge_by_one_col <- function(X, Y, col = "ID"){
  common <- unique(c(X[[col]], Y[[col]]))
  res <- data.frame(common)
  names(res) <- col

  i <- match(X[[col]], res[[col]])
  j <- na.omit(match(res[[col]], X[[col]]))
  for(new in setdiff(names(X), col)){
    res[[new]] <- NA
    res[[new]][i] <- X[[new]][j]
  }

  i <- match(Y[[col]], res[[col]])
  j <- na.omit(match(res[[col]], Y[[col]]))
  for(new in setdiff(names(Y), names(res))){
    res[[new]] <- NA
    res[[new]][i] <- Y[[new]][j]
  }

  res
}

merge_by_one_col(df1, df2)
```

Comment: How general is this solution?

Comment: @Edward `merge` is a generic function. The method `merge.data.frame` is 158 code lines. The solution posted is not general at all.

Comment: I mean, is it possible to modify your solution to not involve the names of the data frames (excluding the "ID")?

Comment: @Edward Yes, that is possible. I would write a function generalizing that code.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I used `cbind` after `rbind`ing the missing IDs from each data frame and sorting by ID.

```
df1_ <- rbind(df1, data.frame(ID=setdiff(df2$ID, df1$ID), Height=NA))
df2_ <- rbind(df2, data.frame(ID=setdiff(df1$ID, df2$ID), Weight=NA))
cbind(df1_[order(df1_$ID),], df2_[order(df2_$ID), -1, drop=FALSE])
```

---

```
  ID Height Weight
1  1     67    110
2  2     60    123
3  3     62     NA
4  4     55    150
5  5     69    170
6  6     NA    185
```

**Edit**:
Generalizing so that no column names are required (except the "by" column "ID")

```
n1 <- setdiff(df1$ID, df2$ID); n1
n2 <- setdiff(df2$ID, df1$ID); n2

df1a <- df1[rep(nrow(df1)+1, length(n1)),]; df1a
df2a <- df2[rep(nrow(df2)+1, length(n2)),]; df2a

df1a$ID <- n2
df2a$ID <- n1

df1_ <- rbind(df1, df1a)
df2_ <- rbind(df2, df2a)

res <- cbind(df1_[order(df1_$ID),], df2_[order(df2_$ID), -1, drop=FALSE])
rownames(res) <- 1:nrow(res)
res
```

---

```
   ID Height Weight
1   1     67    110
2   2     60    123
3   3     62     NA
4   4     55    150
5   5     69    170
NA  6     NA    185
```

**Edit 2**: Using `rbind.fill` from the **plyr** package:

```
library(plyr)

df1_ <- rbind.fill(df1, data.frame(ID=setdiff(df2$ID, df1$ID)))
df2_ <- rbind.fill(df2, data.frame(ID=setdiff(df1$ID, df2$ID)))

res <- cbind(df1_[order(df1_$ID),], df2_[order(df2_$ID), -1, drop=FALSE])

identical(res, merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE))
# TRUE
```